# Spaces between menu items

Tags: html, css

Please, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAzbe/
Where are these spaces from?

HTML:

```
<header>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-sub 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub-sub 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

ul, ol {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 86px;
}
header ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
header > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
header > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 83px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888888;
  background-color: white;
}
header > ul > li:hover > a, header > ul > li.active > a {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  color: #888888;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px #ec5d9d solid;
}

header > ul > li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Add margin-right:-4px; to header > ul > li

Comment: It's a hack :) But why there are these margins?

Comment: This happens due to inline-block. It's a proper technique these days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the thin space between `li` elements, then negate margin.

```
header > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-right:-4px;
}
```

It happens because of `inline-block`. Chris Coyer has something on this [too](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Negative margins are not a good idea for IE 6-7 but who cares anyway.

The other techniques are also valid and they work.

Comment: Thanks for Chris Coyer's link.

Answer (score 1):

Negative margins are not a good idea. Because at the end you will have an indifference.

Set the li to display:block instead of inline-block and then use float:left;

e.g:

```
header > ul > li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
    float:left
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAzbe/1/

Comment: I've been using them all my life, never had an issue with negative margins.

Comment: if you are taking 4px from the right of every menu item. In this case it will mean at the far right will be a 20px gap (after 6 menu items)

It depends what you want to do, nothing wrong with negative margins, they have their place.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
header > ul > li {
  float:left;
  position: relative;
}
```